# Estimating mean curvature of a surface by two perpendicular curves of the surface

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, curvature, orthonormal

Let S be an oriented smooth surface containing a circle of radius 1 and a straight line, which intersect perpendicularly at a point $p\in S$. Show that if the Gauss curvature K of
S satisfies
K(p)=0, then the mean curvature H of S satisfies $∣H(p)∣\leq 1/2$.

​ I tried to solve the exercise above,  by the principal curvatures  k_1,k_2, $K(p)=k_1\cdot k_2 $ and $H(p)=\frac{k_1+ k_2}{2}$ by hypothesis lets say $k_2=0 $, I  also know that the curvature of a straight line equals 0 and the curvature of unit circle is 1, I was thinking Meusnier’s Theorem but I can't make any progress
.

Comment: No, think Euler’s Theorem. As I think you realize, the line and circle needn’t be lines of curvature, but what do you know about normal curvatures in those directions?

Comment: Oh, Meusnier will help with my question, of course.